# How to use sed to split a string?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am new to bash scripting. I want to split the following string,

```
chr14:81370042-81371098(+)
```

into

```
chr14 81370042 81371098 +
```

or

```
chr14:81370042-81371098(-)
```

into

```
chr14 81370042 81371098 -
```

Please tell me how do I do this with one command that would work for both the cases.

I tried, `cat a.tsv | tr -s ':' '\t' | sed "s/\t[0-9]+.*[0-9]+/[0-9]+\t[0-9]/g"`, it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `sed` may work:

```
sed -E 's/[^-+_[:alnum:]]+/ /g; s/ +$//; s/-(.)/ \1/g' <<< 'chr14:81370042-81371098(+)'
```

```
chr14 81370042 81371098 +
```

Or else:

```
sed -E 's/[^-+_[:alnum:]]+/ /g; s/ +$//; s/-(.)/ \1/g' <<< 'chr14:81370042-81371098(-)'
```

```
chr14 81370042 81371098 -
```

`[^-+_[:alnum:]]+` matches 1 or more of any character that is not `-`, `+`, `_` and alphanumeric.

Comment: thanks, that works, but what if I also have to split chr7:26004607-26028902(-) similarly, as the above deletes the (-)?

Comment: but this results in, chr7 26004607-26028902 - and I want it to be chr7 26004607 26028902 -

Answer (score 3):

Written and tested with shown samples, could you please try following.

```
echo "chr14:81370042-81371098(+)" | awk '{gsub(/:|-|\(|\)/,OFS)} 1'
```

***2nd solution:*** Using field separator in `awk`.

```
echo "chr14:81370042-81371098(+)"  | 
awk -v FS=':|-|\(|\)' '{
  $1=$1
  sub(/ +$/,"")
}
1'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed 's/[():]/ /g; s/-/ /' file
chr14 81370042 81371098 +
chr14 81370042 81371098 -
```

or if you don't like the trailing blank char that leaves then:

```
$ sed 's/[(:]/ /g; s/)//; s/-/ /' file
chr14 81370042 81371098 +
chr14 81370042 81371098 -
```